# Detect if all textarea are empty using jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I check whether a group of textareas are all empty using jquery and the textareas class "inside"? I need to check this **inside a if**.

```
<textarea id="1" class="inside"></textarea>
<textarea id="2" class="inside"></textarea>
<textarea id="3" class="inside"></textarea>
<textarea id="4" class="inside"></textarea>
```

Comment: You should probably remove the `.` in `class=".inside"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this would do it

```
if (! $('.inside').filter(function() {return this.value.length;}).length ) {
   // all empty
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XhUdt/)

Filters out any elements that doesn't have a value, and you could optionally use trim to account for whitespace as well "`return $.trim(this.value).length;`", and if the selector has no length, none of the elements have a value.

Comment: I was actually thinking of using a `.each()` loop, but your solution screams BRILLIANT :) +1

Comment: @Terry - Thanks, a filter is often useful for the strangest of things.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.is(':empty')` to check.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3g99p/)

```
$('textarea.inside').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':empty')){
        alert('empty');
    }
});
```

It's worth noting that the class of each element shouldn't contain a `.`. Also, an `id` shouldn't start with a number.

Answer (score 0):

Remove you don't need to use . for class name in html. You use that for selector in jquery syntax.

If all your text area got inside class, you can go over those text area one by one.

Use `$('.inside').each(function(){});` to go over all the elements and update the flag if any textarea got text.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `.inside` isn't a valid class name and won't work as a jQuery selector. Change this to `inside` without the period.

You'll could set a true/false variable for whether they are all empty then iterate over all elements and check for whether they are empty (I'm trimming too to remove whitespace). Here's an example:

```
var allEmpty = true;
$('.inside').each(function() {
    if($(this).val().trim() != '')
        allEmpty = false;
});

if(allEmpty)
    alert('All empty!');
else
    alert('One isn\'t empty!');
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CFK3c/